# I always get a "DeprecationWarning" when using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, browser

I know this question has been asked a number of times but I've tried everything and just haven't found a good solution.
The error I get looks like this:

```
program.py:10: DeprecationWarning: use setter for headless property instead of set_headless 
     fireFoxOptions.set_headless(headless=True)
```

The best thing is to just show you the code and if someone notices a mistake, please write to me! Thank you very much in advance...

```
from selenium import webdriver 


try:
    fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    fireFoxOptions.set_headless(headless=True)         ///Here occurs the error!!!
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=fireFoxOptions)

    browser.get("https://google.com") 
    for elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "elementname"]'): 
        print(elem.text)

finally:
    try:
        brower.close()
    except:
        pass


browser.close()
```

Thank you again so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set_headless is deprecated in selenium now. Instead use the headless property:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```